# Texture is only rendered correctly in first frame

Tags: animation, texturing

I am new to Blender and I am trying to create an animation. My data is saved as a Blender voxel file which I load into a cube, adjust scattering etc. and it looks fine, but the texture is only visible in frame 1 and disappears in the following frames (in object mode and also when rendered).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

[image: Frame 2]
[image: Frame 1]

Comment: It is totally fine to answer your own question. It will make this thread more structured and readable.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of my problem was that I had not set Still Frame Number to 1, see this post: [Bug? Voxel Data Animation Issue (Still Frame Number Keyframe not rendering)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100825/bug-voxel-data-animation-issue-still-frame-number-keyframe-not-rendering?rq=1).

Maybe it helps somebody else.